# Cannot figure out Html Encoding usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-encode

I'm working on MVC web application. I have a page mix of Razor and JavaScript.

**Razor:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    string initialImage = "<img src='/Site_Data/BIO/Bio.jpg' title='BIO'>";
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Photos").fileinput({
        initialPreview: [@initialImage],
```

**What I want is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Photos").fileinput({
        initialPreview: ["<img src='/Site_Data/BIO/Bio.jpg' title='BIO'>"],
```

**What I get (in source view) is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Photos").fileinput({
        initialPreview: [&lt;img src=&#39;/Site_Data/BIO/Bio.jpg&#39; title=&#39;BIO&#39;&gt;],
```

I tried many combinations of HtmlEncode and HtmlDecode (on both Razor and JavaScript section) but could not figure it out.
Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: just use @Html.Raw(initialImage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default asp.net mvc will encode your string. to use the unencoded string use Html.Raw(string):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Photos").fileinput({
        initialPreview: ["@Html.Raw(initialImage)"],
```

Comment: Not working. I get error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.IHtmlString' to 'string'". I used .ToString() and still have invalid characters

Comment: edited the response. used Html.Raw in the wrong place

Comment: I had guessed that might be the issue :). You also need to use double-quote around @Html.Raw(initialImage). I edit your answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Html.Raw renders what it is given without doing any html encoding, 
 so with

```
@Html.Raw(initialImage);
```

will be render as

```
<img src='/Site_Data/BIO/Bio.jpg' title='BIO'>
```

In your js you need to encode it with double qoutes only:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Photos").fileinput({
        initialPreview: ["@Html.Raw(initialImage)"],
```

However, when you have encoded characters in there, such as `ViewBag.Something = "&gt;";` the raw version of that is `&gt;.` To get back to actual html you need

```
Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(EncodedContent));
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation